# linux mint mate panel: move time and date to the right of volume

Tags: linux-mint, mate-desktop, mate-panel

I have Linux Mint 20.3 with MATE 1.26.0.

After messing with some external monitors, and the resolution, and which monitor is the main one, my panel got all messed up.

I managed to "move all the launchers to the usual place, and also managed to move the part with the open windows (I can't remember how that is called).

The problem remains with the "time and date" panel element, which now is on the left of the "system icons", such as volume, network connection, etc (also here, I don't know how to properly call them).
If I right-click the time-and-date panel element, I have the "move" option, but it seems impossible to move it to the rightmost position, i.e. to the right of the system icons.

On the other hand, if I right click the "system icons" they seem to miss the "move" option.

Here is a screenshot of the whole panel:

[image]

and of the right part only:

[image]

So, how can I move the time and date to its original position, the rightmost, to the right of volume icon?

Thanks in advance for any help.

I am relatively new to Linux, so in addition to the solution of the specific problem, I would be happy to have more insights: how to correctly call those things, in particular the icons on the right, and the area with the open windows, understand why they behave differently, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

Control-right-click on the volume icon gives access to a contextual menu:

[image]

First you need to unlock from panel, and then it is possible to move it to the desired position.
The "info" option shows the name of this panel element "Xapp Status Applet":

[image]

Another group of icons is the "Notification Area".
To move this is enough to right-click slightly on the left of it:

[image]

This is its "info window":

[image]

Last, but not least, the "Window List" panel element. To move it you need to right click slightly to its left:

[image]

This is its info window:

[image]